# Concurrent Hash Map get and put overlapping

Tags: concurrency, concurrenthashmap, thread-synchronization

I have read that `get` method is fully concurrent in `ConcurrentHashMap(Jdk 7 )` and so it can overlap with all update operations. What will happen if two threads run `put(Key,V)` and `Get (Key)` concurrently if Key is not already present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JDK7 Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset.

This means `get()` will return `null` if it was invoked before `put()` completed.

The short answer to your question is: `put()` will return `null`.